# Where to place the unload me to make the Private sub work

Tags: excel, userform, vba

I am using a userform and have issue with the "unload me"

If I place the "unload me" before my private sub => the private sub doesn t start

If I place it after, I cannot click in the cell of the new workbook (which is what I see first on my screen when the macro is done)

Where should I put the unload me to make it work properly?

Code below:

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_click()

        Private_Sub

Unload Me

End Sub
```

---

```
Private Sub Private_Sub()

    Workbooks.Open Filename:="U:\mydocuments\Workbook.xlsx"

End Sub
```

Please tell me if I don t make myself clear enough.

Comment: On what part of the code did you opened the `userform`?

Comment: It s on another module (in personal Macro), and is only a sub with  "My_userform.Show" inside

Comment: You should never use Unload Me, you should use Me.hide
https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2017/10/25/userform1-show/

Comment: Using Me.hide instead doesn t solve the problem if I put it at the end (I still don t understand why), but it does work if I leave it at the beginning.

Comment: Me.hide works for me